# Trying to get property of non-object in CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing->getTemplates()

Tags: newsletter

I am trying to allow my users to sign up for newsletter through drupal webform, which adds them to a newsletter group.

Although users can sign up to the group and everything seems ok, when they submit the form following warning appears on screen:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing->getTemplates() (line 763 in */sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing->getTemplates() (line 767 in */sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing->getTemplates() (line 777 in */sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in CRM_Mailing_BAO_Mailing->getTemplates() (line 781 in */sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/Mailing.php).
```

What does it mean and, most importantly how can I get rid of it?

---

Civi - 4.7.1
Durupal 7

Thanks,

Marian

Comment: See this duplicate question posted just after yours! http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9613/error-messages-galore-from-contact-php-and-mailing-php-but-eveything-works-sho/9614#9614